# Joi Schema should contain one field or another

Tags: javascript, joi

I'm looking into using Joi for api validation.

I can't seem to confirm whether my schema is correct in that I want either the email or mobile to be required (but they both can't be empty/non existent) - is the below correct?

```
var schemaForRegistration = Joi.object().keys({
      email: Joi.string().email(),
      mobile:Joi.number().integer()
}).without('email', 'mobile');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 25):

It might be that `or()` is what you're after.

Try this:

```
const Joi = require('joi')

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string().email(),
    mobile: Joi.number().integer()
}).or('email', 'mobile')

Joi.validate({ email: 'xxx@yyy.com', mobile: '999000999000' }, schema, console.log)
Joi.validate({ mobile: '999000999000' }, schema, console.log)
Joi.validate({ email: 'xxx@yyy.com' }, schema, console.log)
Joi.validate({}, schema, console.log)
```

The final validation will fail because neither email nor mobile is present.

Comment: I think you missed an "x", it's xor('email', 'mobile')

Comment: This will fail with this payload: 
```
Joi.validate({ email: 'xxx@yyy.com', mobile: '' }, schema, console.log)
```

Comment: what if there are 5-6 more keys then how "or" will solve purpose ?

Comment: @KartikeyaMishra Did you found out how to do with more keys?

Answer (score 1):

this is just to clarify the uses of `or` and `oxor`.

If you are using `or` It will allow you to add at least one of the required properties. Example

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string().email(),
    mobile: Joi.number().integer(),
    firstname: Joi.string(),
    lastname: Joi.string(),
    address: Joi.string()
}).or("email", "mobile", "firstname", "lastname");

Joi.validate({ email: 'xxx@yyy.com', mobile: '999000999000' }, schema, console.log);
Joi.validate({ mobile: '999000999000' }, schema, console.log);
Joi.validate({ email: 'xxx@yyy.com' }, schema, console.log);
Joi.validate({ firstname: "John" }, schema, console.log);
Joi.validate({ lastname: "Doe" }, schema, console.log);
Joi.validate({ email: 'xxx@yyy.com', firstname: "John" }, schema, console.log);
Joi.validate({}, schema, console.log); // fails
```

Any of these example above are correct, because we specified at least one of the properties that were provided in the `or` method

While for `oxor`
This method says once one of the property listed is provided the validation is correct. But if another property from the list is provided the validation fails.

For example

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string().email(),
    mobile: Joi.number().integer(),
    firstname: Joi.string(),
    lastname: Joi.string(),
    address: Joi.string()
}).oxor("email", "mobile", "firstname", "lastname");

Joi.validate({ email: 'xxx@yyy.com', mobile: '999000999000' }, schema, console.log); // fails
Joi.validate({ mobile: '999000999000' }, schema, console.log); // valid
Joi.validate({ email: 'xxx@yyy.com' }, schema, console.log); // valid
Joi.validate({ firstname: "John" }, schema, console.log); // valid
Joi.validate({ lastname: "Doe" }, schema, console.log); // valid
Joi.validate({ email: 'xxx@yyy.com', firstname: "John" }, schema, console.log); // fails
Joi.validate({}, schema, console.log); // valid
```

As explained above, when using the `oxor` method it will make sure that only one of the listed properties can be used.

Now what if you don't want empty value provided, and you also don't want more than one of the listed property to be used? Then you do it like so.

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string().email(),
    mobile: Joi.number().integer(),
    firstname: Joi.string(),
    lastname: Joi.string(),
    address: Joi.string()
}).or("email", "mobile", "firstname", "lastname").oxor("email", "mobile", "firstname", "lastname");

Joi.validate({ email: 'xxx@yyy.com', mobile: '999000999000' }, schema, console.log); // not valid
Joi.validate({ mobile: '999000999000' }, schema, console.log); // valid
Joi.validate({ email: 'xxx@yyy.com' }, schema, console.log); // valid
Joi.validate({ firstname: "John" }, schema, console.log); // valid
Joi.validate({ lastname: "Doe" }, schema, console.log); // valid
Joi.validate({ email: 'xxx@yyy.com', firstname: "John" }, schema, console.log); // not valid
Joi.validate({}, schema, console.log); // not valid
```

Now the validation process accepts only one property and no empty property.