# Joi validation for mutually exclusive fields with required values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, joi

How can I create a validation rule using Joi that enforces the following condition: if `valueA` is empty, then `valueB` should have a value, and vice versa?

I'm currently using Joi to validate an array of objects that have `valueA` and `valueB` properties. Here's an example of the schema I'm using:

```js
const schema = Joi.object({
  valueA: Joi.string().pattern(/^\d+(,\d{1,2})?(\.\d{1,2})?$/)
  valueB: Joi.string().pattern(/^\d+(,\d{1,2})?(\.\d{1,2})?$/)
});
```

I want to modify this schema to enforce the validation rule that either `valueA` or `valueB` has a value, and the other is empty. How can I do this using Joi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joi either or validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489652/joi-schema-should-contain-one-field-or-another)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this using `alternatives().try()`

Example:

```
const schema = Joi.alternatives().try(
  Joi.object().keys({
    valueA: Joi.string().pattern(/^\d+(,\d{1,2})?(\.\d{1,2})?$/),
    }),
  Joi.object().keys({
    valueB: Joi.string().pattern(/^\d+(,\d{1,2})?(\.\d{1,2})?$/)
    })
);
```

`alternatives().try()` adds an alternative schema type for attempting to match against the validated value. You are passing two options and it will choose one of them.

Comment: No, because when using `or()`, both can have values which I do not want to happen.

Comment: @Nicke7117 Updated answer. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864812/using-joi-require-one-of-two-fields-to-be-non-empty